# Compare 2 sheets and result on sheet 3

Tags: excel, vba

The codes below are edited by me to get the results but unlucky to get it. I am trying to compare sheet1 Col A&B with sheet2 Col A&B and result on sheet3. Kindly advise.

```
Sub ReconcileRegisters()
Dim i    As Long, _
LRa  As Long, _
LRb  As Long, _
rowx As Long

LRa = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LRb = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
rowx = 2
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 2 To LRa
    If IsError(Application.Match(Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:B" & i).Value, Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:B" & LRb), 0)) Then
        Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" & rowx).Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:B" & i).Value
        rowx = rowx + 1
    End If
Next i
For i = 2 To LRb
    If IsError(Application.Match(Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:B" & i).Value, Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:B" & LRa), 0)) Then
        Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" & rowx).Value = Range("A1:B" & i).Value
        rowx = rowx + 1
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Matching process is complete"
```

End Sub

Comment: You need to describe the problem. What errors do you receive and at what line? How is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you compare both loops then I would assume that you need `Sheets("sheet2")` in this second section:

```
Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" & rowx).Value = Range("A1:B" & i).Value
```